Calculating days based on checkin and checkout in hotel billing
I have written a function to calculate days of a person that stays in a hotel which has a 12 hour Noon checkout policy, in C# WPF forms. The function shown here is calculating less days than expected. If checkin_date will be value stored database has this format 2024-08-26 05:04:06.000 and checkout be be current date.
public void GetDays()
{
    status = false;

    // Checkin DATE =2024-08-26 05:04:06.000 AM
    // checkout DATE =2024-08-27 15:04:06.000 PM

    DateTime check_inDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_checkin.Text);
    DateTime check_outDate = DateTime.Now;
     
    TimeSpan ts = check_outDate - check_inDate;

    double NrOfDays = ts.TotalDays;
    double days = Math.Ceiling(NrOfDays);

    bool TwelveHourClockEnabled = cd.Check12hourclock();

    if (ts.TotalDays >= 0)
    {
        int timenow = DateTime.Now.Hour;

        if (TwelveHourClockEnabled)
        {
            if (check_inDate.TimeOfDay.Hours < 12 && check_outDate.TimeOfDay.Hours < 12)
            {
                lbl_days.Text = Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays).ToString();
            }
            else if (check_inDate.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 12 && check_outDate.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 12)
            {
                lbl_days.Text = Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_days.Text = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays).ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // For 24-hour clock, always use ceiling
            lbl_days.Text = days.ToString();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Days Charged: {lbl_days.Text}");
    }
}

Expected output: Days Charged :3

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

It's better to use DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, formatProvider) than Convert.ToDateTime(value) if you know the format ahead of time. It will yield a better result and give better errors.

I think issue is with the checkin checkout policy
double NrOfDays = ts.TotalDays;
double days = Math.Ceiling(NrOfDays);

bool TwelveHourClockEnabled = cd.Check12hourclock();

if (ts.TotalDays >= 0)
{
int checkInHour = check_inDate.TimeOfDay.Hours;
int checkOutHour = check_outDate.TimeOfDay.Hours;

if (TwelveHourClockEnabled)
{
    if (checkInHour < 12 && checkOutHour < 12)
    {
        lbl_days.Text = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays).ToString(); // count as an extra day
    }
    else if (checkInHour >= 12 && checkOutHour >= 12)
    {
        lbl_days.Text = Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays).ToString(); // no extra day, as both are after noon
    }
    else if (checkInHour < 12 && checkOutHour >= 12)
    {
        lbl_days.Text = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays).ToString(); // full day and then some hours
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_days.Text = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays).ToString(); // round up to account for partial day
    }
}
else
{
    // For 24-hour clock, always use ceiling
    lbl_days.Text = days.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine($"Days Charged: {lbl_days.Text}");
}


The following may help -- once you have the timespan you can compute the total days based on whatever business rules you need to follow:
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Test
{
    
   class Program
   {

       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           
           // Format of checkin / checkout date/times ...
           
           const String k_dt_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff tt";
           
           CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
           
           Boolean check_in_out_dt_valid;
           
           String dt_str;
           
           System.DateTime check_in_dt;
           System.DateTime check_out_dt;
           
           System.TimeSpan ts;
           
           
           // Init ...
           
           check_in_out_dt_valid = true;

           check_in_dt = System.DateTime.Now;
           
           check_out_dt = System.DateTime.Now;

           
           // Checkin date/time ...
          
           dt_str = "2024-08-26 05:04:06.000 AM";
           
           try {
               
               check_in_dt = DateTime.ParseExact( dt_str, k_dt_format, provider );
               
               Console.WriteLine( $"{dt_str} converted to {check_in_dt}." );
            
           }
           catch ( Exception ex ) {

               Console.WriteLine( $@"*Error - Unable to parse checkin date/time: {dt_str}, {ex}" );

               check_in_out_dt_valid = false;
               
           }
           
           
           // Checkout date/time ...
          
           dt_str = "2024-08-27 15:04:06.000 PM";
           
           try {
               
               check_out_dt = DateTime.ParseExact( dt_str, k_dt_format, provider );
               
               Console.WriteLine( $"{dt_str} converted to {check_out_dt}." );
            
           }
           catch ( Exception ex ) {

               Console.WriteLine( $@"*Error - Unable to parse checkout date/time: {dt_str}, {ex}" );
               
               check_in_out_dt_valid = false;
               
           }
           
           // If valid checkin/checkout date/times, calculate timespan ...
           
           if ( check_in_out_dt_valid ) {
               
               if ( check_out_dt > check_in_dt ) {
                   
                  ts = check_out_dt.Subtract( check_in_dt );
           
                  Console.WriteLine( $@"Total Days: {ts.TotalDays}" );
                   
                  // Process the timespan according to whatever business rules you need here ...
                   
               }
               else {
                
                   Console.WriteLine( "* Error - checkout date/time must be after checkin date/time" );
                   
               }
               
           }
           else { 
           
               Console.WriteLine( "* Error - check in or check out date/time was not valid" );
               
           }
           
       }
       
    }
    
}


I think you are missing a case where check in was before 12 and checkout after the twelve:
else if (check_inDate.TimeOfDay.Hours < 12 && check_outDate.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 12)
{
    lbl_days.Text = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays + 1).ToString();
}

And then it gives expected result.
